# Learning PHP Error

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn php. The video tutorial I'm following is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TF00hJI78Y. For some reason, I'm not getting the same results as him even though I'm writing the same code. If anyone could help me solve this error, I'd greatly appreciate it.

enterinfo.html is below

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="learnphp.php" method="post">
    <!--php scripts process everything in the html form-->
    <!--post sends data into learnphp.php form-->
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td align="center"><input type="text" name="username"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td align="center"><input type="text" name="streetaddress" size="30" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>City</td>
                <td align="center"><input type="text" name="cityaddress" size="30" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

learnphp.php is below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Information Gathered</title>
</head>

<body>
     <!--
            You embed PHP code between tags
            echo puts what ever is between quotes in the browser

            php code doesn't show if a user tries to view source

            A semicolon has to finish every php statement

            Single quotes : Print what is between them and ignore
                escape sequences except for \' and \\

            Double quotes : Print many escape sequences, the values
                for variables, and more
        -->

    <?php
        echo "<p>Data Processed</p>";

        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

        /* Echos the date
                h : 12 hr format
                H : 24 hr format
                i : Minutes
                s : Seconds
                u : Microseconds
                a : Lowercase am or pm
                l : Full text for the day
                F : Full text for the month
                j : Day of the month
                S : Suffix for the day st, nd, rd, etc.
                Y : 4 digit year
        */


        echo date('h:i:s:u a, l F jS Y e');


    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The result on the web page when I click the submit button is below:

```
Data Processed
"; date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); /* Echos the date h : 12 hr format H : 24 hr format i : Minutes s : Seconds u : Microseconds a : Lowercase am or pm l : Full text for the day F : Full text for the month j : Day of the month S : Suffix for the day st, nd, rd, etc. Y : 4 digit year */ echo date('h:i:s:u a, l F jS Y e'); echo "
"; ?>
```

Comment: input type is not closed properly

Comment: You are echoing a closing </p> tag without an opening <p> before it.

Comment: *groan* typo questions........... off-topic.

Comment: I've fixed the input type and the echo statement. I still get a weird output.

Comment: you're obviously running this from your own computer without a web server installed then

Comment: @Fred-ii-Thank you. I'm looking up how to install a web server now. I'll remove this question since it's probably been covered and not well received

Comment: you're welcome. good catch eh? ;-)

Comment: @pHorseSpec did you try deleting the question, or is it not letting you because of an answer given?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, it won't let me delete the question because there are answers.

Comment: @pHorseSpec I posted an answer for you below if you wish to accept it in order to close the question.

Comment: I posted an answer below. If you want me to delete it, let me know, but you'll have to take it up with Marc to see if he wants to delete his answer in order for you to delete the question; if he doesn't then there's nothing I can do about it, but you could flag your own question and asked for it to be deleted. I posted mine in thinking that you would mark it as solved. Keep me posted, thanks. Cheers. @pHorseSpec

Comment: @Fred-ii- I flagged the question. If they want to remove it, they'll remove it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [start php, apache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016375/start-php-apache)

Comment: @pHorseSpec No problemo, *cheers*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is, that you're trying to run this from your own computer without having a web server installed, that is why you're seeing "source code" appear in the output rather than being properly parsed by PHP.

- PHP code gets parsed differently than browser html files.

There are few packages you can install such as Wamp, Xampp, MAMP, depending on your platform.

References:

- https://www.mamp.info/ - (MAMP) OS X and Windows
- https://www.apachefriends.org/ - (Xampp) Windows, Linux, OS X
- http://www.wampserver.com/en/ - (WAMP) Windows

Answer (score 2):

Typos:

```
            <td align="center"><input type="text" name="username"
                                           missing ></td>    ---^
```

Comment: they've made a Stealth edit. My guess; [is this...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805164/learning-php-error#comment49658876_30805164). Look under *"The result on the web page when I click the submit button is below:...."* - it's pretty obvious. Which is a comment I originally made about that, but deleted it. I shouldn't have done that, because I too thought it was about the typo.

Comment: [I was right.........](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805164/learning-php-error#comment49658993_30805164)